# Is this the actual 16.04 release of Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, 16.04

I have gone to the Ubuntu GNOME website. There is no announcement stating that there is the 16.04 release. It still says the latest is Wily. The thing is that on http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/xenial/release/ there is now the 16.04 files, which was not there earlier today.

Another thing is that there is no download for Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity on the Ubuntu site.

How can I check if this is the stable 16.04 Ubuntu GNOME release before installing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule Canonical will release Xenial today, so there will likely be a Xenial with Unity soon.

As the Ubuntu GNOME images you refer to are released today in accordance with the schedule, one must assume they are the "final release" ones.